# Scatter / Gather using Rebus

Tags: rebus

I have a requirement to a batch a number of web service calls on the receipt of a single message appearing in a (MSMQ) queue.

Is "sagas" the way to go?

The interaction with the 3rd party web service is further complicated because I need to call it once, then poll subsequently for an acknowledgement with a correlation id, returned in the reply to the initial call to the web service.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sagas could be the way to coordinate the process of initiating the call, polling until the operation has ended, and then doing something else when all the work is done.

If you don't care too much about accidentally making the web service call more than once, you can easily use Rebus' `async` capabilities to implement the polling - I am currently in the process of building something that basically does this:

```
public async Task Handle(SomeMessage message)
{
    var response = await _client.Get<SomeResponse>("https://someurl")   ;
    var pollUrl = response.PollUrl;
    var resultUrl = response.ResultUrl;

    while(true)
    {
        var result = await _client.Get<PollResult>(pollUrl);

        if (result.Status == PollStatus.Processing)
        {
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
            continue;
        }

        if (result.Status == PollStatus.Done)
        {
            var finalResult = await _client.Get<FinalResult>(resultUrl);

            return new SomeReply(finalResult);;
        }

        throw new Exception($"Unexpected status while polling {pollUrl}: {result.Status}")
    }
}
```

thus taking advantage of `async`/`await` to poll the external webservice while it is processing, while consuming minimal resources in our end.